# Manipulate objects in the browser with three.js using the mouse

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have this piece of code (see below) that I used to draw a cube with `three.js`:

```
        // revolutions per second
        var angularSpeed = 0.0; 
        var lastTime = 0;

        function animate(){
            // update
            var time = (new Date()).getTime();
            var timeDiff = time - lastTime;
            var angleChange = angularSpeed * timeDiff * 2 * Math.PI / 1000;
            cube.rotation.y += angleChange;
            lastTime = time;

            // render
            renderer.render(scene, camera);

            // request new frame
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        }

        // renderer
        var container = document.getElementById("container");
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(container.offsetWidth, container.offsetHeight);
        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        // camera
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
        camera.position.z = 700;

        // scene
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // cube Length, Height, Width
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(400, 200, 200), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            wireframe: true,
            color: '#ff0000'
        }));
        cube.rotation.x = Math.PI * 0.1;
        scene.add(cube);

        // start animation
        animate();
```

Does anyone know whether is it possible to allow the user to change the size of the cube by dragging the edges using the mouse?

Comment: i suggested an edit for your question including a syntax modification : you wrote `requestAnimationFrame(function(){animate()});` thats the longer but same meaning as `requestAnimationFrame(animate)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Atrahasis/b05m3Lqg/). I reused the structure of [draggableCubes](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html), plus little changes :

- to drag the **vertices** i created vertexHelpers (little spheres);
- to avoid maths the trick is to use an invisible plane to drag your objects/vertices on, perpendicular to the camera. To see it in action, just set `plane.visible=true`
- now we can correctly drag a vertexHelper, its distance to the center of the cube changes. We just have to scale the cube at the same ratio :

Within the `mouseMove` listener's function it becomes:

```
if(SELECTED){

    var intersects=raycaster.intersectObject(plane);
    //so we get the mouse 3D coordinates in intersects[0].point

    var previousDistance=SELECTED.position.sub(cube.position).length();
    var increaseRatio=intersects[0].point.sub(cube.position).length()/previousDistance;

    cube.scale.set(
         cube.scale.x*increaseRatio,
         cube.scale.y*increaseRatio,
         cube.scale.z*increaseRatio
         );

    //then update the vertexHelpers position (copy the new vertices positions)

}
```

---

EDIT :
In your question you precisely ask to resize a cube by dragging its **edges**. I did not remember it in the example and did not think about it intuitively, but it can be done the same way.

However, given `lineWidth` is not implemented in ANGLE (the program used on windows to translate WebGL), it is not easy to pick lines with a 1px-width. I remember a threejs example I could not find, where a geometry is associated to the line so it looks outlined. Basically you could do it by creating a cylinder as custom 'edgesHelpers' (i'm precisely not talking about the `THREE.EdgesHelper`) and they have to be resized each time the cube is too.

Comment: Thanks a lot Astark. Actually dragging the vertices is fine as well, I played with your example and I realised that the user can interact well in this way as well. Do you think is it possible to make the vertices independent from one to the other? i.e. one can drag a vertice without affecting the others?Thanks a lot

Comment: yep, thats an other question but by mistake thats what i coded first : just switch to edit mode

Answer (score 0):

In your setup code add an eventlistener for mousemove:

```
        // Event Handlers
        renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
```

Then in the event handler code, you can check which object is selected and adjust the scale parameter.

```
function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
    ...
    var selected = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);
    if (selected.length > 0) {
        // Do things to the scale parameter(s)... Just for demo purposes
        selected.scale.x = selected.scale.x + selected[0].point.sub(offset).x / 1000;
        selected.scale.y = selected.scale.y + selected[0].point.sub(offset).y / 1000;
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Since I am typing pseudo code here, all too easy to make an error, so I have left a test version here for you to try: http://www.numpty.co.uk/cubedrag.html
As you can see, size of selected object changes in horrible ways with the dragging of the mouse. You have me interested, so will look into making it proportional to movement if I get more time.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mentasm, so I looked into the code in your example and it seems that each paper is a single instance (paperGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2.10, 2.97, 0.01);) Actually, what I'm trying to do is to have just one instance (let's say a cube) and make the edges of the cube draggable. So that one can drag an edge and keep the others fixed. And as a result you will have a deformed cube. Thanks a lot again for your answer.

Comment: Hi Dede, instead of scale, you would alter the geometry based on mouse movement. I happen to have 64 bits of paper and allow you to alter x/y in a random sense, but this should put you on track to achieve what you want to do... j